# Issues with my javascript. Error: is assigned a value but never used. [no-unused-var]

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to make a sales tax calculator. I got it to calculate everything, but there are errors in my functions that I made to clear the textboxes. Any help would be appreciated, still a noob with html/css/js. Basically in Brackets I'm seeing that for each function in my .js file, my functions arent actually being called. An error pops up for each of them saying "is assigned a value but never used".

```js
var $ = function(id)
{
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

var processEntries = function()
{
  var inpSubTotal = parseFloat($("subtotal").value);
  var inpTaxRate = parseFloat($("tax_rate").value);
  if (inpSubTotal <= 0 || subtotal > 10000)
  {
    $("subTotalsMessage").innerHTML = "Subtotal must be > 0 and < 10000";
  }

  if (inpTaxRate <= 0 || inpTaxRate > 12)
  {
    $("taxRateMsg").innerHTML = "Tax rate must be > 0 and < 12";
  }

  var calTax = inpSubTotal * (inpTaxRate / 100);
  calTax = parseFloat(calTax.toFixed(2));
  var totAmt = inpSubTotal + calTax;

  $("sales_tax").value = calTax;

  $("total").value = totAmt.toFixed(2);
}

var clear_click = function()
{
  $("subtotal").value = "";
  $("tax_rate").value = "";
  $("total").value = "";
  $("sales_tax").value = "";
}

function clearSubTotal()
{
  $("subtotal").value = "";
}

function clearTaxRate()
{
  $("tax_rate").value = "";
}

window.onload = function()
{
  $("calculate").onclick = processEntries;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Sales Tax Calculator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />



  <script src="sales_tax.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="content">
    <h1>Sales Tax Calculator</h1>

    <p>Enter Subtotal and Tax Rate and click "Calculate".</p>

    <div id="myTaxCal">
      <label for="subtotal">Subtotal:</label>
      <input type="text" id="subtotal" onclick="clearSubTotal()">
      <span id="subTotalsMessage">Enter order subtotal</span><br />

      <label for="tax_rate">Tax Rate:</label>
      <input type="text" id="tax_rate" onclick="clearTaxRate()">
      <span id="taxRateMsg">Enter sales tax rate (99.9)</span><br />
      <label for="sales_tax">Sales Tax:</label>
      <input type="text" id="sales_tax" disabled><br />

      <label for="total">Total:</label>
      <input type="text" id="total" disabled><br />

      <label>&nbsp;</label>

      <input type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate">

      <input type="button" id="clear" value="Clear" onclick=textClearer()><br />

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with [java](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info)?

Comment: _"is assigned a value but never used"_ sounds like a linting (syntax check) error and not an actual runtime error. Where are you seeing these errors?

Answer (score 1):

i don't see any errors in your code when I run it on code pen. the only thing is that textClearer doesn't exist. I changed it to clear_click and it worked.

`<input type="button" id="clear" value="Clear" onclick=clear_click()><br />`

Answer (score 0):

Your `clear_click` variable function is never used. You are assigning it's value by making it a function variable, but I'm not seeing it being used like `clear_click()`.

Answer (score 0):

The code by itself works as you posted it: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jJYoww

```
is assigned a value but never used
```

This is really more of a warning than an error, and should only be disruptive if you're using a linter or something.

As @Phil asked, where are you seeing the errors, and are you doing anything else to this aside from what is posted?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change function name `clear_click` to `textClearer`

```js
var $ = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

var processEntries = function() {
  var inpSubTotal = parseFloat($("subtotal").value);
  var inpTaxRate = parseFloat($("tax_rate").value);
  if (inpSubTotal <= 0 || subtotal > 10000) {
    $("subTotalsMessage").innerHTML = "Subtotal must be > 0 and < 10000";
  }

  if (inpTaxRate <= 0 || inpTaxRate > 12) {
    $("taxRateMsg").innerHTML = "Tax rate must be > 0 and < 12";
  }

  var calTax = inpSubTotal * (inpTaxRate / 100);
  calTax = parseFloat(calTax.toFixed(2));
  var totAmt = inpSubTotal + calTax;

  $("sales_tax").value = calTax;

  $("total").value = totAmt.toFixed(2);
}

var textClearer = function() {
  $("subtotal").value = "";
  $("tax_rate").value = "";
  $("total").value = "";
  $("sales_tax").value = "";
}

function clearSubTotal() {
  $("subtotal").value = "";
}

function clearTaxRate() {
  $("tax_rate").value = "";
}

window.onload = function() {
  $("calculate").onclick = processEntries;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <h1>Sales Tax Calculator</h1>

  <p>Enter Subtotal and Tax Rate and click "Calculate".</p>

  <div id="myTaxCal">
    <label for="subtotal">Subtotal:</label>
    <input type="text" id="subtotal" onclick="clearSubTotal()">
    <span id="subTotalsMessage">Enter order subtotal</span><br />

    <label for="tax_rate">Tax Rate:</label>
    <input type="text" id="tax_rate" onclick="clearTaxRate()">
    <span id="taxRateMsg">Enter sales tax rate (99.9)</span><br />
    <label for="sales_tax">Sales Tax:</label>
    <input type="text" id="sales_tax" disabled><br />

    <label for="total">Total:</label>
    <input type="text" id="total" disabled><br />

    <label>&nbsp;</label>

    <input type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate">

    <input type="button" id="clear" value="Clear" onclick=textClearer()><br />

  </div>
</div>
```